# DataSource to ListItemCollection

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-controls

I'm looking for a way how is it bound that data from DataSource can be accessed via Item property on ListControl Class.

Can anyone give me an example how properties from passed object to DataSource are bound to generic class ListItemCollection? How that translation can be done by a code?

The translation I'd like to see is from DataSet to ListItemCollection. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Setting up a dataset.  This dataset has no data; in real life you'd get the
// data from somewhere else, such as a database, and wouldn't need to build it.

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ID"));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Description"));
ds.Tables.Add(dt);

// Creating a list box. You'd probably have this declared in your HTML and wouldn't need to
// create it.  

ListBox listBox1 = new ListBox();

listBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
listBox1.DataValueField = "ID";
listBox1.DataTextField = "Description";
listBox1.DataBind();
```

If your question is about how the binding is done behind the scenes, that has a fairly complex answer.

Comment: Yes my question was how is it done behind scene. I need an idea how to take value provided in DataTextField then bind it with ListItem.Text  field.. maybe some links showing any example - i'm searching and seraching..

Comment: You might look at this article:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163816.aspx.  Towards the end it talks about how `TypeDescriptors` are used in WebForms databinding and shows how the `DataBinder.Eval` function is implemented.